# Question about diagonalization of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

`The following question is taken from Pg. no. 156 of "Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd Edition)" by Sheldon Axler.`

Define $T\in L(R^2)$ by
\begin{equation}
T(x,y)= (41x + 7y, -20x + 74y)
\end{equation}
The matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $R^2$ is
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix} 41 & 7 \\ -20 & 74 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which is not a diagonal matrix. However, $T$ is diagonalizable, because the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(1, 4), (7, 5)$ is
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix} 69 & 0 \\ 0 & 46 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now I understand the first part that the matrix formed by standard basis is
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix} 41 & 7 \\ -20 & 74 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
since for $(1,0)$ we have $(41+0, -20+0)$ and for $(0,1)$ we have $(0+7, 0+74)$ and so the matrix is of the form given above.

However, in the second part for the basis $(1, 4), (7, 5)$, should it not be something like this
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix} 41(1)+7(4) &  41(7)+7(5) \\ -20(1)+74(4) & -20(7)+74(5) \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Also, how can we guess a basis for which a matrix is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $T(1,4) = (69,276) = 69(1,4)$, and similarly $T(7,5) = (322,230) = 46(7,5)$, which is why the resulting matrix is diagonal.

> Also, how can we guess a basis for which a matrix is diagonalizable?

You don't have to guess: the basis consists of eigenvectors for the linear transformation.